# TNT is ruining my minecraft experience

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I block users from igniting TNT and blowing up my creations when I am hosting a server?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What type of server are you using, pocketmine, local, or ordinary?

Answer (score 3):

You can place a command block near your creations and set it to repeat and always active. Write this command in:

```
/kill @e[type=tnt]
```

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
/gamerule tntExplodes false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Pocketmine server, there are plugins to block TNT. If you're running a local, or ordinary server, there is no current method to block it.